# Css property being removed, while capturing html

Tags: html, css, angular, go, chromedp

I am facing an issue with css property. Let me explain the flow, I am getting the style from api , and implementing it inline on the html. This html including the style is being scanned on backend and the html is captured.At the time of html capturing font-size property is being removed.And rest all the other property works fine.

I am using [chromedp](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp) package to capture the html in go language, using the following code

```
func main() {
    url := "url_from_where_you want to capture html"
    componentSelector := "#root"
    html := CaptureHtml(url, componentSelector)
    fmt.Println(html)
    return

}

func CaptureHtml(url string, componentSelector string) (template.HTML, error) {
    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(context.Background())
    defer cancel()
    err := chromedp.Run(ctx, chromedp.Navigate(url), chromedp.WaitVisible(componentSelector, chromedp.ByQuery))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return "", err
    }

    // Sleep to ensure the data rendering is complete
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    var htmlContent string
    // Capture the HTML content of the element containing the rendered API data
    err = chromedp.Run(ctx, chromedp.OuterHTML(componentSelector, &htmlContent, chromedp.NodeVisible))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return template.HTML(htmlContent), err
}
```

What could be the reason of a particular css property being removed?

Comment: Really I don't know, but check if the same happens with others properties like "margin-right" (properties that have a `-`) and check if you're provide a valid value of the font-size

Comment: No, I dont think there is any issue with properties having '-' because other properties like 'font-weight', etc works fine.